# Getting Unknown filter type [icu_collation] for [icu_collation_filter] error when trying to index data in opensearch

Tags: indexing, plugins, opensearch

URI [/<index_name>?include_type_name=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
Warnings: [299 OpenSearch-1.0.0-34550c5b17124ddc59458ef774f6b43a086522e3 “[types removal] Using include_type_name in create index requests is deprecated. The parameter will be removed in the next major version.“]
{“error”:{“root_cause”:[{“type”:“illegal_argument_exception”,“reason”:“Unknown filter type [icu_collation] for [icu_collation_filter]“}],“type”:“illegal_argument_exception”,“reason”:“Unknown filter type [icu_collation] for [icu_collation_filter]“},“status”:400}